# springfox-swagger2 @ModelAttribute suppression

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using springfox-swagger2 and want to suppress the @ModelAttribute from generating documentation. Does anyone know an easy way I can set a property in my configuration class so it skips over these fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `@ModelAttributes` cannot be suppressed. However specific classes can be. For e.g. if you have a controller method

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void someMethod(@ModelAttribute SomeModel)
```

you could ignore the type `SomeModel` and it will not be rendered or shown in the swagger api description. You can do this by adding to the `ignoredParameterTypes` in your `Docket`